# Question regrading NPObject onwership when calling NPN_InvokeDefault()

Tags: javascript, npapi

I have written an `NPAPI` plug-in to interact with `JavaScript`. My `JavaScript` code loads this   plug-in and makes an Async call on it supplying a callback. When the callback (JS) needs to  be   invoked from my `plug-in`, I'm calling `NPN_InvokeDefault()`. The parameters I want to pass   to the `JavaScript` include: An `NPObject` that I have created and converted that to `NPVariant` before passing to `NPN_InvokeDefault().` My question is who takes the ownership of this object  - Am I responsible for freeing this Object by calling `NPN_ReleaseVariantValue()` ? Or is this   owned by `Webkit` (in JS context)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably want to look at my blog post on the subject: http://npapi.com/memory

The short answer is that anything that you retain control of after a call you should release.  Since with InvokeDefault you still have control of your NPVariant array afterwords you need to release all of the NPVariants; if the code on the other side of InvokeDefault needs to hold on to it it is responsible for retaining, copying, etc as needed.

The only exception to this rule is that when you return a NPVariant from a function on your NPObject you lose control of it and the browser is responsible for releasing it; similarly anything that the browser returns to you from InvokeDefault (the return value) it is your responsibility to release.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for that elaborate discussion about NPAPI in your blog. I found it very helpful. One more question though. When I do NPN_InvokeDefault() , if I see webkit code, inside this function, they are calling NPN_RetainObject() on the NPObject I'm passing(when they create CInstance for javaScript). So at what point are they expected to release their reference? Or should I release all the references myself (by calling NPN_ReleaseObject repeatedly till ref count becomes zero and NPN_Deallocate gets called on my NPObject) when the plug-in is unloaded? Is this advisable?

Comment: uh, no.  that would really defeat the whole purpose of reference counting. Whoever calls Retain is responsible to call Release, and you never call release for something else.  Doing so would probably result in a crash. The browser will release it when it is ready.

Comment: also worth noting that when you call NPN_CreateObject there is an implicit Retain involved there, so when you are done with it you should call NPN_ReleaseObject on it.  The exception to this rule is some versions of WebKit, now older versions, incorrectly did not do the implicit retain; you can find workarounds for this in projects like FireBreath (www.firebreath.org)